# Why a class or a list in a python has the id() but has a different variable

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I try to shared some within different process.
There is a very easy way to use mp.Array(). Here I use a class, just like the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class SharedData(object):
    shared_data = 0

class A(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print('b_address', self.data)
            print('a_data', id(self.data.shared_data))
            print('a_class', id(self.data))
            self.data.shared_data += 1

class B(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print('b_address', self.data)
            print('b_data', id(self.data.shared_data))
            print('b_class', id(self.data))
            print(self.data.shared_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = SharedData()
    a = A(data)
    b = B(data)

    a.start()
    b.start()
```

I found that the id of the class SharedData in class A and class B are the same. And in class B, the id of shared_data is a constant. But the id of the shard_data in class A changes. In my opinion, if the id of two classes are the same, the classes shared the same memory. But why I cannot share the data in processes?

Comment: The `id` is only guaranteed to be unique and constant in one process.

Comment: So the data with same id in two processes means nothing?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes